# Unreal Engine 4.22 Could not find definition for module

Tags: c#, c++, unreal-engine4

I'm taking a course for Unreal Engine 4 and I seem to have run into a compilation error.

I only have maybe 3 days experience with Unreal.
I am an expert at C++.
I have never touched C Sharp before which is why it is irritating that C Sharp is being used in small parts of the example project when I was promised that only C++ is used in Unreal Engine 4 projects.

The logfile ends as follows:

> LogVSAccessor: Warning: Couldn't access Visual Studio
>
> Candidate modules for hot reload:
>
> BullCowGame
>
> Launching UnrealBuildTool... [C:/Program Files/Epic Games/UE_4.22/Engine/Binaries/DotNET/UnrealBuildTool.exe  -ModuleWithSuffix=BullCowGame,6263 Win64 Development -TargetType=Editor -Project="C:/Users/school/Desktop/unreal_course_projects/bull_cow_game_attempt_2/BullCowGame-starter-kit/BullCowGame.uproject" "C:/Users/school/Desktop/unreal_course_projects/bul
>
> l_cow_game_attempt_2/BullCowGame-starter-kit/BullCowGame.uproject"  -IgnoreJunk]
>
> Warning: Starting HotReload took  1.5s.
>
> CompilerResultsLog: New page: Compilation - May 6, 2020, 9:08:11 PM
>
> CompilerResultsLog: Using 'git status' to determine working set for adaptive non-unity build (C:\Users\school\Desktop\unreal_course_projects\bull_cow_game_attempt_2\BullCowGame-starter-kit).
>
> CompilerResultsLog: Creating makefile for BullCowGameEditor (game project files are newer)
>
> CompilerResultsLog: ERROR: Could not find definition for module 'BullCowGame' (referenced via BullCowGameEditor.Target.cs)
>
> LogMainFrame: MainFrame: Module compiling took 37.379 seconds
>
> Warning: HotReload failed, recompile failed
>
> LogSlate: Window 'Message Log' being destroyed
>
> LogSlate: Window 'Message Log' being destroyed

BullCowGameEditor.Target.cs:

```
// Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.

using UnrealBuildTool;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class BullCowGameEditorTarget : TargetRules
{
    public BullCowGameEditorTarget(TargetInfo Target) : base(Target)
    {
        Type = TargetType.Editor;

        ExtraModuleNames.AddRange( new string[] { "BullCowGame" } );
    }
}
```

BullCowGame.Target.cs:

```
// Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.

using UnrealBuildTool;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class BullCowGameTarget : TargetRules
{
    public BullCowGameTarget(TargetInfo Target) : base(Target)
    {
        Type = TargetType.Game;

        ExtraModuleNames.AddRange( new string[] { "BullCowGame" } );
    }
}
```

The project layout:

[image: BullCowGame_layout_1]

**The error I'm trying to fix: *ERROR: Could not find definition for module 'BullCowGame' (referenced via BullCowGameEditor.Target.cs)***

You can see this error towards the bottom of the log file.
Has anyone seen this before?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score -3):

Looking at your project layout, you are missing `.../Source/BullCowGame/BullCowGame.Build.cs` which describes how to build the BullCowGame module.

See: https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/ProductionPipelines/BuildTools/UnrealBuildTool/ModuleFiles/index.html